# Listen for specific keys pressed on input - ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am building a component in React that is supposed to be a time picker. I want to constraint the input to only allow numbers and backspaces and not allow more than two digits in the input. My component is built like this:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

class Example extends component {
    state = {hour: "00"}

    hourEdited = (event) => {
        this.setState({hour: event.target.value});
    }

    render() {
        <input type="number" value={this.state.hour} onChange={this.hourEdited.bind(this)} />
    }
}
```

My initial thought was to try to check for `event.keyCode` and check if the keyCode of the event was a code for a numeric value or backspace. That was not correct. How do I do this?

I also thought that if input was of type "number" you could only enter numbers but that isn't the case for me at least.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this. For some reason the `input type="number"` was not behaving the way I at least thought it should. I just subbed the wrong characters and checked if the event value exceeded two letters. Here is my new hourEdited function:

```
hourEdited = (event) => {
    let newValue = event.target.value;

    if(newValue.length <= 2) {
        this.setState(hour: newValue.replace(/[^0-9]+/g, "");
    } 
}
```

Hopefully this helped if others run into this!